# Pointers ABC. error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘struct config’)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a basic problem. I should know enough about pointers by now. The way I see it configData is the first link in a linked list (of the type struct config) while procNames is a pointer to the first link in a linked list of the type struct config. So if I want to say that procNames is equal to configData then I need to access the pointer that points to configData which is `*configData`. Anyhow I think I am missing something. Anyone sees the problem? Also, I get the next error: error: `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘struct config’)`

```
struct config_line {
    char name[MAX_WORD];
    int time;
};

struct config {
    struct config_line *lines;
    int count;
};

//global variable
struct config configData;
//local variable
struct config *procNames;
//the problem (done locally) 
procNames = *configData;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
procNames = &configData;
```

This sets the pointer `procNames` to the address of the structure `configData`.

You can access the elements using either

```
procNames->count
procNames->lines[i].name  // Pointer to the 1st char of the name in the i'th config_line structure
```

or

```
configData.count
configData.lines[i].name
```

Remember that, since `lines` is itself a pointer, you'll need to allocate memory for each `config_line` structure:

```
struct config_line thisLine;   // Declare a structure
procNames->lines = &thisLine;  // Point to it
```

or

```
// Declare a pointer to an array of structures, allocate memory for the structures
struct config_line *linePtr = malloc(NUM_STRUCTS * sizeof(struct config_line));
procName->lines[i] = *linePtr; // Points to 1st structure in the array
```

Comment: wouldn't it be procName->lines[i] = *linePtr?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description of what you are trying to do, you need to take the address of configData (write &configData on the last line). What you are trying to do on the last line is dereference configData, which the compiler will not let you do since configData is not a pointer (it does not store an address inside).

The error message is fairly clear on this. Unary * takes a single pointer as an argument, but the argument used of type struct config, and not a pointer.